# AudioFileOpenURL unable to open raw pcm file

Tags: ios, objective-c, audioqueue

I'm using `AudioQueueServices` to play a raw pcm file. Let's call it `somePcm.pcm`.

I'm using the following line to open the file:

```
AudioFileOpenURL(myFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &player.playbackFile)
```

where `myFileURL` is the URL pointing to where `somePcm.pcm` is, and `player.playerbackFile` is the `AudioFileID`.

When I step through my code, `playbackFile` points to memory location 0x0000000000000. Basically it cannot open the file and represent it as an audio file object.

Things to note:

1. I replaced the url with some `.mp3` file, and it works fine. Therefore, I'm not sure exactly what's wrong with that line of code.
2. The `.pcm` file does play, thus it is not corrupted.

Is there some alternative method to open an audio file? Or if someone sees what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result code from `AudioFileOpenURL`? The Audio File Services Reference documentation gives you a list, which should describe the problem. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I got a kAudioFileUnsupportedFileTypeError. This is very confusing, as from what I'm googling, people don't seem to have this problem. Also, I downloaded Audacity, and it is using Core Audio to play this .pcm file that I'm having....so wierd.